# Moving a .sdf file into isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

How do I move a .sdf file into my isolated storage and after I have moved it is there a way to delete it as it is of no use. I have added my .sdf file as a content in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but let me see if I get this.  You created a database, added it to your file as content to your project so that you can have all the data present when the user installs your app.  Then you are copying the data from the read-only .sdf file into a database that you are creating on first run, so that you can read/write to it.  Correct?

If so, I do not believe there is a way to delete the read-only file that you included with the install.

If your database is large enough that you are concerned about the space it will take by having two copies of it on the phone, I would suggest placing your data on a server, creating a web service, and access that web service on first run.  Place a notice on the screen that lets your user know that it is downloading information that will only be downloaded once, and that subsequent launches will not take as long.  Be sure you include code to prevent a problem should the download be interrupted by a phone call, text message, back key press, start button, or other event.  Make it be able to continue the download if it was interrupted in a prior run.

Comment: [link](http://www.wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app/)  I found an answer there.I found that there is no way to delete content once the app is installed from your answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, .SDF is a format of Microsoft SQL Server Compact (SQL CE) databases. The link you have pasted talks about SQLite databases.

This the way to download the entire Isolated Storage onto your device.

Open cmd and go to the following directory

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool

then use the isetool.exe to download the Isolated Storage along with the .sdf file onto your machine.

isetool.exe ts xd [Product_id_here_see_WMAppManifest.xml] "D:\Sandbox"

You should get message like download successful into D:\Sandbox.

You can also upload the sdf by changing the argument **ts** with **rs**